# Add html link into text input box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to add a HTML link to an input box using the following jQuery:

```
var E = "<a class='tagged_person' contenteditable='false' href='http://www.google.com'>Click This</a>";
$("input[name='newComment']").val(E);
```

Which is working, but its literally displaying the `<a href...`, which is what I wanted backend wise, but on the frontend, I'd like the user to see it as rendered as a HTML `<a>` link. Just like  on Facebook/Twitter you can tag users and then there's a link.

Comment: I don't think you can have a clickable-link directly in an input box.

Comment: Would it be acceptable to have the link just be over top of part of the input box?  That is doable.  Having it directly in the input is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code, which when select it will open the link in a new window.

```
<form action="../">
<select name="myDestination">
    <option value="http://www.website1.com/">Website 1</option>
    <option value="http://www.google.com/">GOOGLE</option>
</select>
<input type="button"
    value="Open in New Window!"
    onclick="ob=this.form.myDestination;window.open(ob.options[ob.selectedIndex].value)">
</form>
```

Or without the need to press a button:

```
<form action="../">
  <select onchange="window.open(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,'_top')">
    <option value="">Choose a destination...</option>
    <option value="http://www.website1.com/">Website 1</option>
    <option value="http://www.google.com/">GOOGLE</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Also created a jsfiddle to demonstrate: [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/aghZQ/)

Comment: FYI: If you want nice formatted code, put a new line between text and code, and just indent every line of code 4 spaces. Using the backtick is only for `if you want code` in the middle of a line of text.

Comment: Thanks ngmiceli for the tip, I'll re-edit it now. Also upped your comment :).
Edit: Nevermind, Nikola K beat me to it.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking for the JQuery method `.append`. That lets you pass a string of HTML and have it parsed into the DOM. [Check it out here](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

For example:

```
$('#myDiv').append('<a href="www.google.com">Search for it!</a>');
```

There's also [`.appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) if it suits your aesthetic better.

**Edit**: If you're trying to literally stick html as the value of a text input, you can't do that.  `<input type="text">` carry text, and that's it. You'd have to make your own input form, or use a JQuery plugin. Why would you want to have a link in a form input anyway though? Sure, you could have the user redirected when clicking the form through different event handlers, but input is for *inputting*. If it redirects, then you didn't really want an input in the first place.